# A word for someone who comes from one city but supports a team from a different city?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes someone who, for example, supports Manchester United but was neither born nor brought up in Manchester but comes from another city in the UK?

I'm not looking for a rude or humorous word but rather a descriptive one.

Comment: The phrase for a Man utd supporter who doesn't come from Manchester is "most Man Utd fans".

Comment: @DJClayworth - It does feel like that sometimes.

Comment: Only one word for that: Traitor!

Comment: A football turncoat?

Comment: Maybe just a fan?

Comment: If the only reason they support their adopted team is that the team is usually a championship contender, you might call them _frontrunners_ or _bandwagon jumpers_. But some fans adopt a team simply because they like its style of play or its persona/image. And in the United States, at least, some teams have long streaks of not winning championships and yet have national followings; such enthusiasts are informally known as _masochists_ or _Cubs fans_.

Answer (score 4):

*Plastic fan* (or just *plastic*) fits your description, but it tends to be a derogatory term. Here is the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Plastic%20Fan) entry:

> A person who roots for a Non-Hometown team based on that teams good
>   record.

Comment: What does 'roots' mean, and what is its origin? It is never used in Britain in this sense.

Comment: Good answer. But how do you describe the millions around the world, from Beijing to Cape Town who support an English Premiership side. In Malaysia, a country with which I am familiar, the favourite English team is Liverpool, and you will see almost as many Gerrard shirts as you will see in parts of the UK.

Comment: @WS2 See "root (v.2)" in the Online Etymology Dictionary http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=root

Comment: @Michael Broder  I'm not much clearer after reading it, I'm afraid, except that it originated with baseball, and that there was an intermediate meaning of 'study or work hard'. But why root?

Answer (score 1):

Not a single word answer, but *[glory hunter](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Glory%20Hunter)* fits the bill if the supported club is more successful than the hometown club.